# Bootstrap - Image in Page header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, image

I would like to add an image as a page header, but can't get rid of the top margin.
See the red section
[image]
Currently this is html

```
<div class="page-header">
    <img src="./eroforrasok/logo3.jpg" class="img-fluid page-header" alt="Responsive image" >
</div>
```

and CSS code

```
.page-header {
  padding-top:0px;
  margin: 0px 0 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

I also tried

```
fixed-top
```

which eliminated the top margin, but then the image was always in the top, 
I could not scroll down the image...
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to add `body{ margin: 0 }` in your css

Comment: @Nidhi thank, I tried but still no luck. But I discovered, that I had a padding-top 20px in my body, which caused this...

Comment: ok, can you add working snippet or jsfiddle link which shows your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If think you misinterpret the purpose of `.page-header` a little bit :

> A simple shell for an h1 to appropriately space out and segment
>   sections of content on a page. It can utilize the h1's default small
>   element, as well as most other components (with additional styles).

But if you insists you should never use an `<img>` tag inside a `.page-header`. Use a `background-image` instead; a fixed height and `background-size` set to `cover` does the "magic". Example :

```css
.page-header h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.page-header {
  height: 60px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(some/parth/to/image);
}
```

```html
<div class="page-header">
  <h1 class="text-primary">My awesome page header</h1>
</div>
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pxu4gb6c/**